# Error in Spark while declaring a UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to create a udf which takes a value(array) in a column and returns an array containing only unique elements . Please see the code below in Spark (version-1.6.1):

```
def uniq_array(col_array):
    x = np.unique(col_array)
    return x

uniq_array_udf = udf(uniq_array,ArrayType())
```

However, I am continuously running into the error:
`TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Can anyone please help me resolve the error as soon as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

For ArrayType, the type of the contents of the array also needs to be specified, eg

```
def uniq_array(col_array):
    x = np.unique(col_array)
    return x

uniq_array_udf = udf(uniq_array,ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```